# SQL Server and Persisted computed field with Hashbytes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Before changes I had a persisted computed field which used `Checksum` function and index to use it.

```
alter table Softs add TitleHash AS (CHECKSUM([Title])) PERSISTED;
```

All were fine until we found that Checksum produces poor hash and duplicates might occur. So we decided to use Hashbytes.
I tried both with binary result and char result

```
alter table Softs add TitleHashCBin AS (CONVERT(BINARY(16),hashbytes('MD4',[Title]))) PERSISTED;
```

or

```
alter table Softs add TitleHashCChar AS (CONVERT(CHAR(32),hashbytes('MD4',[Title]),2)) PERSISTED;
```

Unfortunately we found that a simple SELECT request **does not** use index for new field.

```
SELECT id FROM Softs WHERE TitleHashCBin = 0xC29939F6149FD65100A66AF5FD958D8B
```

**It scans primary index which is build on `Id` column.**

After that we created binary column, copied data from TitleHashCBin and also created index for new column.

```
alter table Softs add TitleHashBin AS Binary(16)
```

And used similar select statement.

```
SELECT id FROM Softs WHERE TitleHashBin = 0xC29939F6149FD65100A66AF5FD958D8B
```

And this one uses index by TitleHashBin field.
What a hell is going with calculated fields. Can somebody explain what I'm doing wrong or is it a bug?
P.S. Sql Server 2008  10.0.3798

**Edit**
I just removed char column from the table to investigate what does SSMS generate. It generated actually the same as you described.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
COMMIT
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
--DROP INDEXes here
--GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Softs DROP COLUMN TitleHashCChar, TitleHashChar
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Softs SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT
```

So I think we can assume that table options are correct.
After that I repeated select statements but with the same execution plan as before...

**Edit**
I resolved to task using simple binary fields and Insert/Update triggers to update them. Works like a charm. But it is still unclear why it has so strange behavior?..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your set options are correct, from [BOL Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx)

SET Option Requirements
The ANSI_NULLS connection-level option must be set to ON when the CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE statement that defines the computed column is executed. The OBJECTPROPERTY function reports whether the option is on through the IsAnsiNullsOn property.
The connection on which the index is created, and all connections trying INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statements that will change values in the index, must have six SET options set to ON and one option set to OFF. The optimizer ignores an index on a computed column for any SELECT statement executed by a connection that does not have these same option settings. 
The NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT option must be set to OFF, and the following options must be set to ON:

ANSI_NULLS

ANSI_PADDING

ANSI_WARNINGS

ARITHABORT

CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL

QUOTED_IDENTIFIER

Setting ANSI_WARNINGS to ON implicitly sets ARITHABORT to ON when the database compatibility level is set to 90. If the database compatibility level is set to 80 or earlier, the ARITHABORT option must explicitly be set to ON. For more information, see SET Options That Affect Results.

Comment: Thank you! I've updated my post with new information from you. Options seem to be correct but unfortunately result is the same...